# Accessing a Tkinter widget directly by its name when held in a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a complicated GUI interface and to keep the code in my `__init__` method as concise as possible I like to create widgets of the same type in a list. My question is how can I access a particular widget by name if it is held in a list without iterating through the list and comparing the name.

Here is some example code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def change():
    for l in labs:
        if l._name == s.get():
            l.configure(text="Changed")
            return

labs = []
for x in range(5):
    labs.append(tk.Label(root, text="Original", name=str(x)))
    labs[x].pack()

b = ttk.Button(root, text="Change", command=change)
s = tk.Spinbox(width=2, values=[0,1,2,3,4])
s.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In the `change()` function I want to configure the text without iterating through the entire list. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not use a dict instead of a list?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. The root.children method was okay but when I tried it in my actual code it was very unwieldy. Like self.children["frame_name"].children["label_name"]. A dictionary is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, perhaps this is the correct way:

```
def change():
    root.children[str(s.get())].configure(text="Changed")
```